# Determine the joint density of the pair $U=X,V=X/Y$. Then use it to show that $X/Y$ has the standard Cauchy distribution.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid. standard Normal random variables. Determine the joint density of the pair $U=X,V=X/Y$. Then use it to show that $X/Y$ has the standard Cauchy distribution.

I know that X and Y have a pdf of $g(x)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, and I know that the joint density, $f(x,y)$, must be such that $P{(x,y)\in A}=\int\int_Af(x,y)dxdy$, where A is an event. I don't really know how to go about starting this question, but the only workings I have so far is
$$
P(X<x,X/Y<x/y)=P(X<x,Y>\frac yxX),
$$
but I'm not sure that is even relevant. Also this comes from the chapter do with convolutions and generating functions, so there is a chance that the solution is something to do with convolutions or generating functions. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard normal distribution is $~ N (0, 1)$.

So if $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables,

$f_{XY}(x, y) = \cfrac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}}{2\pi}, \  -\infty \leq x, y \leq \infty$

Now $U = X, V = \cfrac{X}{Y} \implies X = U, Y = \cfrac{U}{V}$

$|J| = \cfrac{|U|}{V^2}$

So, $ \ f_{UV}(u, v) = f_{XY} \left(u, \cfrac{u}{v}\right) |J|$

$ =  \cfrac{|u|}{2 \pi v^2} e^{-\frac{u^2 (1+v^2)}{2v^2}}, \  -\infty \leq u, v \leq \infty$

Comment: I don't think I'm familiar with this technique you have used. Is this something to do with a Jacobian? Is there any other way to solve this problem or do you recommend that I look into Jacobian things?

Comment: @WillHarris Yes we can find cumulative distribution and then differentiate but this is easier. Yes it is to do with Jacobian. I can explain if you have questions.

Comment: Haha how much time do you have? Not sure what questions to start asking really

Comment: Is there anywhere you could point me to read more about what you have done here?

Comment: @WillHarris https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_4_functions.php see example $5.29$

Comment: Okay thank you I understand now. I do remember now that I have learned about this stuff a while ago. If you feel like it, could you help me out with the next part of the question: use this to show that X/Y has a standard Cauchy distribution?

Comment: @WillHarris for that just integrate $f(u, v)$ with respect to $u$ with bounds $-\infty, \infty$. You will get $\cfrac{1}{\pi(1+v^2)}$ which is indeed the standard Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense. Thanks very much for your help Math Lover.